# pronunciation and meaning of the word 干支崩年

Tags: kanji

I have this sentence from a text which mentions the death of two emperors, but I cannot find the meaning and pronunciation of 干支崩年 in it. The sentence is:

> "古事記の干支崩年に従えば、応神天皇の崩御が西暦394年、仁徳天皇の崩御が西暦427年となり、その間が在位期間となる。"

I cannot find the expression 干支崩年 in the online dictionary. If I copy only the first 2 kanji it lists the reading of 干支 as "eto" or "kanshi" and the meaning as "sexagenary cycle; Chinese astrology". But together with 崩 and 年 it doesn't list anything.

Does anyone know of this expression?

Comment: thanks for editing, i few points I messed up, but I don't agree with all the changes, thanks anyway.

Comment: fair enough, if you don't agree with any of my changes feel free to roll them back.

Comment: :D well most of them fair, I just can't get it how I overlooked them.
Anyway now at least I realized how I can form my question through using quotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [article](http://kodai.sakura.ne.jp/nihonnkennkokusi/2-1hougyo.htm), it looks like (in this case at least,) the meaning of this compound has to do with describing the reigning period of particular emperors (in the Kojiki) by using the [sexagenary cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle) instead of giving a particular Western calendar year.  Historians can then estimate emperor reign length against Western (or other) calendars by using this sexagenary cycle notation.

Also, the 崩年 compound itself [can be read](http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/kawakatu_1205/40839299.html): ほうねん.

Interesting topic!

***Reference:***

1. http://kodai.sakura.ne.jp/nihonnkennkokusi/2-1hougyo.htm
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle

Comment: Thank you for your links and your answer it is very helpful!:) Japanese is a really exciting language, many times confusing but exciting and beautiful!

Comment: @DajkaLaszlo No problem!  Yeah, that's a good description of the Japanese langauge :)